# Make action cache from script in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching, action

I want to make action cache from my script without reference to domain name, because we don't know unicorn's address. So, I must call controller's action in some 'internal' way.

I tried

```
app = ActionDispatch::Integration::Session.new(Rails.application)
app.get(app.api_v1_items_url)
```

But, this seems to produce cache in different location (I don't know where) than a location in which Rails.cache.clear clears cache. Any idea?

EDIT

Our controller implementation is

```
class Api::V1::ItemsController < Api::V1::ApplicationController
  caches_action :index, cache_path: Proc.new { api_v1_items_path }

  def index
    ...
```

So, domain name is not included in cache path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, my solution is not wrong. I make some rails s restarting mistake.